# Start service from main application icon

Tags: android, service

My application is basically a service, i.e. has no UI (there isn't any class subclassing Activity). I want to have it displayed in the list of applications and to run the service when it's started from there, with the advantage that the user can create a shortcut to display it in the home screen.

Is this possible?

Comment: Creating a dummy Activity that starts the service and then finishes itself does the trick, but I'm a little worried about the flashing of the Activity loading and closing.

Comment: Just have it display some sort of success message and then let the user click ok to close..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution to this:

1. Create an `Activity` and in the `onCreate(...)` method call your service and then call `finish()`.
2. To prevent the flashing of the `Activity` opening and closing, use this as the theme of your `Activity` (in the AndroidManifest.xml):

   android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"

Comment: One can prevent flashing of the `activity` using `Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar` but can anything be done about the time taken in between that, which is around a second.

Answer (score 1):

Just make one Activity that allows the user to configure your application. Also there surely must be some sort of UI as part of the app. Otherwise what is it actually doing and how does the user control it?

Comment: There's no configuration needed in this app. The service displays a Toast to give the user feedback that is running.

Comment: thats probably not good. It should use a Notification .. anyway.

Comment: In this case the service does a pretty small job, and only one notification to the user is needed and the notification should be displayed immediately. I think that given this case a Toast fits better than a Notification.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to have it displayed in the list of applications and to run the service when it's started from there, with the advantage that the user can create a shortcut to display it in the home screen.

That is not a "list of applications". It is a list of activities that have advertised via `<intent-filter>` that they are to appear in the launcher. The key word is "activities".

> Creating a dummy Activity that starts the service and then finishes itself does the trick, but I'm a little worried about the flashing of the Activity loading and closing.

Then create an activity that adds value to the user.

Comment: Thanks, so if it's a list of activies then there is no way to hack this :(